# What happens when you ignore HTTPS warning?

Tags: tls, x.509

I’m setting up a router at home, and I just created a CA and signed a cert with it. The first time I navigated to the router console, I was greeted with the familiar scary Safari warning about insecure certificates. I bypassed it, since I know the certificate was mine.

What exactly does the browser track so that it does not complain the next time I navigate to the website? Does it track the url? Public key? Something else? I would like to make sure that if I am in fact being MITMed, the browser would recognize that the malicious certificate is different than the one I chose to ignore the warnings for.

Comment: What browser are you using? In my experience, the browser only remembers until you close the browser. Unless you install the cert.

Answer (score 1):

The browser associates the domain in the URL (or IP if no domain name given) with the specific certificate observed. This means same certificate, different domain -> no trust. Same domain, different certificate -> no trust. Same domain, same certificate -> trusted.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the exact problem that is reported by the browser. You did not specify how exactly your self-signed certificate looks, so I see two possibilities (or a combination of both):

**a) Untrusted certificate**

The trust store of your OS holds a list of trusted certificates. Because X.509 certificates are based on a hierarchical trust concept, your OS comes with a long list of trusted certificates, so-called root certificates. Root certificates are always self-signed.

If you create a self-signed certificate, this certificate cannot be found in the trust store. Therefore, the browser issues a warning that the validity of the certificate cannot be verified.

If you agree to add an exception rule, the certificate is added to either your personal trust store or to the browser's custom trust store. As a consequence, next time the certificates is encountered, it will be considered trusted.

**b) Domain or IP mismatch**

When an SSL (aka TLS) connection is established, the certificate is checked against the domain name or IP address that was used to connect to the site. The domain name or IP address in the URL must be listed in the certificate, otherwise the browser warns of a mismatch.

If you override the mismatch, an exception might be added so the browser accepts the certificate for the given URL despite the mismatch. However, this type of exception is usually only valid for the current session and not stored as a permanent exception, but the exact behavior depends on the browser.